# Hide dummy taskbar icon for notification icon context menu

Tags: c#, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

I have a simple .Net 5.0 WinForm form which is automatically hidden after the application started:

```
private void form_Shown (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide ();
}
```

It only creates a notify icon. This notify icon has a context menu strip that is shown by a *left* mouse click:

```
private void notifyIcon_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuStrip.Show (MousePosition);
}
```

This works fine, but as long as the context menu strip is visible, a dummy taskbar icon appears:

[image]

This doesn't happen if the form is not hidden or the context menu strip is shown by a *right* mouse click (via ContextMenuStrip property).

How can I prevent this icon?

Comment: Are you talking about the `ShowInTaskbar` property?

Comment: Not at all (and changing this to false did not solve the problem).

Comment: Don't use a Form.  House your NotifyIcon in an ApplicationContext derived class and run that in Application.Run() instead of a Form in program.cs.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution myself:

```
[DllImport ("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow (HandleRef hWnd);

private void notifyIcon_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetForegroundWindow (new HandleRef (notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip, notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Handle));
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Show (MousePosition);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Me.Hide()

lets see the outcome

Try assign your context menu to the notifyicon`s .ContextMenu property like and use the notifyicon`s .Visible property to show it instead of using the .Show method.

Comment: This doesn't change anything as the form is already invisible.